# Unity AltspaceVR Uploader Fails - EditorCoroutine.cs "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to upload a Unity project via the AltspaceVR Uploader and I've followed all the steps for migrating to the correct Unity version (2020.3.18f1) and converted all materials to Universal Render Pipeline, but when I attempt to upload I receive these error messages and I don't know how to go about fixing them. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

I've tried creating a fresh blank project and that uploads correctly. I've also tried removing everything from my scene but that still fails, so it seems to be failing because of whatever the issue is with this EditorCoroutine.cs script.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bit that seems promising.
http://plbm.com/?p=221

Following those instructions, the bit of code that is causing the exception is:

```
if(advance)
                {
                    data = default(ProcessorData); 
                    return enumerator.MoveNext();
                }
                return true;
```